# Fill a CheckedListbox from a database based on checked values of another CheckedListbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am using SQL Server 2016 Visual studio 2017.
Need to fill `checkedlistbox2`, from my database, based on the value of the SelectedItem of `Checkedlistbox1`.

I am filling `checkedlistbox1` on Form.Load as below:
This code is working.

```
Private Sub fillChkboxList()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.200.36;user id=sa;password=XXXX@123;database=XXXXXXX")
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter("select DepartmentName, DepartmentID from DepartmentMain where active=1 order by DepartmentName", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    sda.Fill(dt)
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = dt
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName"
    CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentID"
End Sub
```

Here I am trying to use a method to fill `Checkedlistbox2`, which I am calling in the `ItemCheck` event handler of `Checkedlistbox1`:

Below Code is not giving required results

```
Public Function fillChkboxListSub()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim conn1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.200.36;user id=sa;password=XXXX@123;database=XXXXXXX")

    With CheckedListBox2
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
                Dim xx As String = (CType(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataRowView))("DepartmentID")
                Dim sqlstr2 As String = "select SubName,SubDeptID from DepartmentSub where active=1 and DepartmentID in ('" & xx & "') order by SubName"
                Dim command2 As New SqlCommand(sqlstr2, conn1)
                Dim adpt2 As New SqlDataAdapter(command2)
                adpt2.SelectCommand = command2
                adpt2.Fill(dt2)

                CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt2
                CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "SubName"
                CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "SubDeptID"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

This function I am calling on:

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    fillChkboxListSub()
End Sub
```

I am not getting the result.
If I check the (`DepartmentName`) in `checkedlistbox1`, `SubDeptName` should load in `checkedlistbox2`. If I deselect the same in `checkedlistbox1`, it should be deleted or removed from `checkedlistbox2`Please help with working code example.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems that at every checked item you start a query to extract the dependent records and replace whatever you have put in the list in the loop before. You need FIRST to extract all the checked items and add them to a list. Only at the end of the loop ask for the data to insert in the second list

Comment: Are you aware that the `ItemCheck` event is raised BEFORE the state of the item changes? You need to look at the `e.NewValue` property to know whether the item is being checked or unchecked.

Comment: Pls suggest some working example

Comment: Dear All, Pls help me in correcting the code, i am trying the same for 4 days but not getting the correct answer, pls help with code example or correct me in above coding

Comment: Functions require a datatype and a return statement. If you aren't returning anything use a Sub.

Comment: `For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1` Why are you skipping so many items?

Answer (score 1):

Most database objects need to be disposed. `Connection`s, `Command`s, and `DataReader`s have a `Dispose` method that must be called to release unmanaged resources that they use. It is made easy for us with `Using...End Using` blocks that ensure that `Dispose` is called even if there is an error.

The order of setting the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, and `ValueMember` is important. Setting **DataSource** should be **last** line. If you set `ValueMember` before `DataSource` no action is triggered. If you set `Datasource` first, the box will bind value member for you. Then, you're going to set a new `ValueMember` (the one you want) and box will have to re-wire binding. So, if you set `DataSource` last, bindings will happen only once.

You can use the `CheckedItems` collection to loop through. Add eacn item to a list. After the loop use `Join` with a comma separator to prepare the In clause for the sql string. I used an interpolated string to build the sql string indicated by the preceding `$`. Variables can then be inserted in line surrounded by `{ }` .

```
Private CnString As String = "Data Source=192.168.200.36;user id=sa;password=XXXX@123;database=XXXXXXX"
Private Sub fillChkboxList1()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(CnString),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("select DepartmentName, DepartmentID from DepartmentMain where active=1 order by DepartmentName", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName"
    CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentID"
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
Public Sub fillChkboxList2()
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Dim drv = DirectCast(item, DataRowView)
        Dim DepId As Integer = CInt(drv("DepartmentId"))
        lst.Add(DepId)
    Next
    Dim DepIdString = String.Join(",", lst)
    Dim sql As String = $"select SubName,SubDeptID from DepartmentSub where active=1 and DepartmentID in ({DepIdString}) order by SubName"
    Debug.Print(sql) 'See if your select string looks correct.
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(CnString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "SubName"
    CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "SubDeptID"
    CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Above Code is giving me some syntax error like incorrect syntax near ')'. and by giving datasource before display member is filling my first checkedlistbox, below value member is not giving me results

Comment: I am guessing that this error is coming from the query string. Can you let me see the string the printed in the Immediate window?